# Make a POST inside GET request good practice?

Tags: javascript, next.js

As the title says, I want to make a POST request while making a GET request.  Is this good practice? Or a huge no-no?

This is because my app functionality works as follows: on page load, it needs to get the user data. If the user data isn't in the database, it should be added to the database. There is no sign up.  We are keeping track of all users on the page. (How many times they've viewed the site and an ID)

EDIT: we are not keeping track of users log in information. Or signing them up. We're keeping track of how many times they've viewed the website in our database.

I've tried setting it up with a GET then onSuccess run a POST request, but that seems overdone.

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    // check db if user is there (db.get())
    // if not run the PUT request. (db.save())
  } 
}
```

Comment: Signing up users who just visit your page but did not consent to account creation might violate legal regulations. Signing up users by GET requests - including when they follow links - does circumvent some default security mechanisms and might open you up to attacks. So yes, it's a bad idea. Still, it can be done responsibly, particularly if the effect is [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) and the GET always returns the same resource.

Comment: @Bergi Edited my post. We are not signing up users. Just keeping track of how many times they've viewed the site: both guest and logged in users.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with logging GET requests. That some POST request happens to store this log in your database is an implementation detail and does not affect the semantics of the HTTP GET request.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way. If you're using DynamoDB, for example, you may be able to use [UpdateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html). This allows you to update an item if it exists, or post a new item if it doesn't. Additionally, by using the `ReturnValues` parameter, the operation will return any attributes you desire. It's possible you can get everything you want with a single one of these calls.

But if not, this looks fine to me. If you want to avoid nested callbacks, you can separate the calls using `async` and `await` syntax:

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  if (req === "GET") {
    const result = await getRequest();
    if (result.isEmpty()) {
      postRequest();
    }
  }
}
```